# Matching ? with regex using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match this string "end='w'?>" using Regex with in c#
Here's what i've got:

```
Regex regexcontentLength = new Regex(@"(?<=end='w'\?>)(.*?)(?=\r\n--)");
contentLengthMatch = regexcontentLength.Match(content);
```

I think is the "?" question that causing me not to match.I have tried multiple combinations and I cannot seem to get this to match. I point in the right direction with be uberly helpful!

Comment: What are you trying to match? What is the input string? If you want to match a literal `?` then you should use `\?`

Comment: @MatiCicero - the string contains: "end='w'?>" and "\r\n--" and I want to grab everything in between. It's an image file and data in between is encoded so theres no point posting the entire string, its really huge lol

Comment: The \? isn't working. As you can see in the code snippet above

Comment: Try with `@"(?s)(?<=end='w'\?>)(.*?)(?=\r\n--)"`. Make `.` match a newline.

Comment: I give that a shot. I let you know if it works in just a few.

Comment: @MatiCicero - Hey man that worked!!!! I appreciate your help. Put your answer in the answered section so I give the points for your help.

Comment: @JosephFreeman Wow! Glad I could be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
@"(?s)(?<=end='w'\?>)(.*?)(?=\r\n--)"
```

Make `.` match a newline.

Comment: well the answer you gave me that was adding "(?s)" to the regex